ASP.NET Core MVC hosting project to Godaddy
I try to host my ASP.NET Core MVC project to godaddy cpanel, after publishing the project into the folder in Visual Studio, it's actually work fine in my local host (IIS), but on godaddy I get a http 403 forbidden error
This response from godaddy when I navigate the url of the project
The files in godaddy look like this:
enter image description here
web config looks like this
Please, help me to solve this problem, 10 hours and I can't find the solution.
BTW, I add pipelines to program.cs UseStaticFiles(); to access wwwroot files
Here is publish windows configurations in visual studio

You may check whether you have setup your default page correctly or not. Please also read this blog https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-solve-error-403-forbidden-error-in-asp-net/.

Does it work well if you enter complete URL with controller and action instead of the root URL? Besides, as @TheGunners suggested, do you try to configure default document for your site?
